# Кол-во ожидающих пуллов для стабильной работы

Tags: mysql, node.js, pool

Поставил на node.js mysql, и сделал пулл соединение. Но вот вопрос такой, сколько пуллов ставить, что бы стабильно работал сервер? Читал что кто то ставит 500, кто-то 50, понимаю что зависит от тачки и кол-ва юзверей, но все-же встал такой вопрос..

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10 // по дефлоту стоит 10 подключений
});
```

Работаю с вебсокетами, и на каждого юзера получается 1пулл, даже если боты сидят на сайте, им тоже пулл дает, и из-за этого реальный трафик может недождаться своей очереди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала хочу отметить, что у вас есть очевидные проблемы с терминологией. Для взаимодействия с базой клиент использует *соединение*, а [*пул соединений*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) отвечает за управление (установку, поддержание, переработку...) сразу нескольких параллельных соединений с базой данных.

Далее, пул соединений в модуле [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) в node.js умный - он устанавливает ровно столько соединений, сколько необходимо. Если вы укажете `connectionLimit: 100`, но будете использовать не более 5 соединений *одновременно* то пул создаст всего 5 соединений. Вот что об этом написано в [официальной документации](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections):

> Connections are lazily created by the pool. If you configure the pool to allow up to 100 connections, but only ever use 5 simultaneously, only 5 connections will be made. Connections are also cycled round-robin style, with connections being taken from the top of the pool and returning to the bottom.

Что касается конкретного значения, то определить эту величину можно только экспериментально. Для начала можете установить размер пула в 50 соединений и если кто-то из клиентов действительно будет простаивать в очереди за соединением - можете увеличивать это значение.

Дополнительно можно задать для пула опцию `acquireTimeout` с каким-нибудь небольшим, приемлемым для вашего приложения значением. Если вы будете логировать все ошибки запросов к БД, то сможете легко понять нужно ли вам увеличивать пул или его размера достаточно.